# Is 'take some food with yourself' grammatically correct?

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

The real subject is 'you' and the object is 'you' too.
So do I have to use'yourself' or 'you'?
By saying 'take' I mean 'carry'.

Comment: First of all, it is not a full sentence. In Instant Message-type language, many things are said. So...."Johnny, take some food with yourself for the trip". Is it pretty? It is elegant? No. Might it be said, yes. Could it be just with you? Yes, it could. Would I say it? No. Would I say: Take some food with you? Yes, I might.

Comment: Not unless you are camping. You only carry food if you actually carry it. Take food is fine. Carry/take are not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Take some food with yourself" it is [technically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_pronoun) correct, because the subject and the object are both "you."  However, a native speaker would simply say "Take some food with you."

Having "yourself" in a sentence where the word "you" isn't even spoken is an awkward construction.  I would expect there to be a reason.  For instance, you might want to emphasize their identity.  I might say:

> "You are ditching me to go to some lousy concert?  Go by *yourself*, then!"

In this case, I'm using "yourself" to emphasize that *I* will not be there; you will be on your own.  We will not be going as a group.

Non-standard usage of "yourself" is getting more popular, but at the moment "take some food with you" is the most natural sounding phrasing to a native speaker.